# PHP show blank value in dropdown list that's fed NULL value from database

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a setup for showing years in my webform that updates each year that's working good.

Since I need to do math on the year value selected by the user, I've made it an INT in the MySQL database.  Making the value INT returns a zero to the select field where ever the user hasn't put any information in.  The user will leave some of these fields empty.

Here's the code I'm currently using to populate the year select box:

```
<div class="kstyle">
    <label for="c02">C #02&nbsp;</label>
    <select id="c02" name="c02">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="<?=$row['c02'];?>" selected><?=$row['c02'];?></option>

<script>
    var min = new Date().getFullYear() - 45;
    cur = new Date().getFullYear();
    select = document.getElementById('c02');

    for (var i = min; i<=cur; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.text = i;
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
    </script>
    </select>
</div>
```

This returns a zero in any INT field that doesn't have a value selected.

The issue I'm running into is an aesthetic one.  I'd like the page to show a completely blank result whenever the database returns zero/NULL.

I'm working on tweaking the above code with an if - else statement but keep running into syntax errors associated with equal signs, left and/or right carrot signs.  This tells me that these values are being evaluated as arithmetic, which means I probably need to tweak where I put parenthesis and/or quotes.  This however is outside the bounds of what I've read in the PHP manual, so I need some help.

Here's where I'm at right now with the code:

```
 <div class="kstyle">
    <label for="c03">C #03&nbsp;</label>
    <select id="c03" name="c03">
    <option value="<?php if($row['c03']=NULL)
    { echo '';
    } else {
    <$row['c03']; selected><$row['c03'];}>?>"></option>

    <script>
    var min = new Date().getFullYear() - 45;
    cur = new Date().getFullYear();
    select = document.getElementById('c03');

    for (var i = min; i<=cur; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.text = i;
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
    </script>
    </select>
</div>
```

If anybody could show me where I'm screwing up or a different approach to this, I'd be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for 0 and null with:

```
<?= !empty($row['c02']) ? $row['c02'] : null ?>
```

But, why not generate all the options with PHP:

```
$minY = date('Y',strtotime('-45 years')); // ## 45 Years Ago
$curY = date('Y'); // ## This Year
$selY = !empty($row['c03']) ? $row['c03'] : null; // ## Resultset Year

echo "<select id=\"c03\" name=\"c03\">\n";
echo "\t<option value=\"\">Select a Year</option>\n"; // ## Blank/Prompt Option
for($i = $minY; $i <= $curY; $i++) {
    $selected = ($i == $selY) ? 'selected' : null;
    echo "\t<option $selected value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>\n";
```

The `"\n"` (newline) and `"\t"`(tab) are not necessary but result in more legible code.  This should give you something like:

```
<select id="c03" name="c03">
    <option value="">Select a Year</option>
    <option  value="1972">1972</option>
    <option  value="1973">1973</option>
    ...
    <option  value="2017">2017</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This seems to be working.  I appreciate changing the javascript to php.  The php looks like it's working...Appreciate the support.

Comment: If HTML5 is an option (and compatibility is not an issue) you might be able to use `<input type="number" name="year" min="<?= $minY ?>" max="<?= $curY ?>">` for a cleaner, lighter, alternative.

Comment: Another part of my site has dates into the future.  I tweaked the code to support that, but now I'm running into the 2038 issue with strtotime.

Comment: No need to use strtotime, just add/subtract from `$curY = date('Y');` as needed: `$minY = $curY - 45;` or `$maxY = $curY + 45;`

Comment: Ahhh, I'm tracking now...was working on using:  http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm not quite understanding what you're trying to do, it just looks like your output syntax is wrong.

Try this?

```
    <option value="<?php 
        if($row['c03'] == null){ 
            echo '">';
        } else {
            echo $row['c03'] . '" selected >';
        }
    ?>
    </option>
```

Comment: sorry, was missing the closing curly brace. try now

Comment: It submits the data to the database correctly but displays a blank field.I've played around with the quotes and carrot signs to try to get it to close the option field properly, but everything I've tried ends up showing up as symbols in the dropdown menu

Answer (score 1):

First ting first, your if condition is wrong. Compare it with ==

```
if($row['c03']==NULL)
```

Second,You say you have 0 value in the database and if condition is checking NULL, which I think is wrong. It should be

```
if($row['c03']==0)
```

And there is syntax error for option tag. It should be like this

```
<option value="<?php if($row['c03']==0)
    { echo '';
    } else {
    $row['c03'];?> selected><?php echo $row['c03'];}?>"></option>
```

Comment: I think the code should be `<option value="<?php if( $row['c03'] == NULL ) { echo ''; } else { echo $row['c03']; ?>" selected><?php echo $row['c03']; }?></option>`

Comment: Also, why not use a ternary operation instead of if else i.e. `<option value="<?php echo ( $row['c03'] == NULL ) ? '' : $row['c03']; ?>" selected>`

Comment: Thanks for the solution Ravinder....I would have spent a ton of time before I realized I should have changed the if evaluation criteria to zero instead of null!

Comment: Junaid...I'll take a look at your recommendation as well.  Appreciate the look at this from different angles...

Comment: My first test showed blank for the zero values, unfortunately, when I try putting different values in from the select box, it keeps returning blank.

Comment: Can you provide input and expected output as example